# How to set up a private key using SecretManager in FirebaseAdmin in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Thanks for your time.

I am currently developing in GCP and Firebase using Laravel.
In order to use Firebase Admin SDK in the development, I am storing the JSON private key of Firebase Admin SDK in SecretManager of GCP.
I am thinking of using it in Laravel by retrieving it from SecretManager, but I don't know how to pass the JSON private key retrieved from SecretManager to the Firebase setting file.

Firebase.php

```
   'credentials' => [
        'file' => env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS', env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')),

        /*
         * If you want to prevent the auto discovery of credentials, set the
         * following parameter to false. If you disable it, you must
         * provide a credentials file.
         */
        'auto_discovery' => true,
    ],
```

.env

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=resources/credentials/firebaseCredential.json
```

We apologize for the inconvenience,
I would like to know if anyone knows anything about this.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the Google Cloud Secret Manager client library for Laravel:

```
composer require google/cloud-secret-manager
```

Update config/firebase.php

```
'credentials' => [
 'file' => env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS', env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')),
 'json' => config('firebase.json'), // Add this line
 'auto_discovery' => true,],
```

In your Laravel code, you can use the Google Cloud Secret Manager client library to retrieve the secret and then set it in the `config` during application boot-up. This can be done in the `AppServiceProvider` or any other appropriate service provider.

```
enter code here
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Google\Cloud\SecretManager\V1\SecretManagerServiceClient;

// ... inside a service provider's boot() method or another appropriate    location
$secretManager = new SecretManagerServiceClient(); 
$secretName = 'projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/secrets/YOUR_SECRET_NAME/versions /latest';

try {
    $response = $secretManager->accessSecretVersion($secretName);
    $secretPayload = $response->getPayload()->getData();

    // Decode the JSON payload and set it in the Firebase credentials config
    Config::set('firebase.json', $secretPayload);
    }
 catch (\Google\ApiCore\ApiException $e) {
    // Handle the exception if secret retrieval fails
   }
```

Replace `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` and `YOUR_SECRET_NAME` with the appropriate values from your Secret Manager setup. Since you are loading the credentials dynamically from the Secret Manager, you no longer need  `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS`

Comment: Thank you for contacting us.
I have tried the above solution,
I get the following error and cannot execute it.

Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set to the JSON file path, but when I run it in Docker, an error occurs in the CredentialsLoder.

I would like to know if you know of any solutions.